# Problem with create new directory in Flutter App

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with creating a new directory in Flutter app (testing on iOS simulator). The path I get after function create() is just a root path, not a new directory path. Does anyone know this problem? Please help me.

My code is below:

```
  static Future<String> createDirectory(String folderName) async {
    final Directory _localStorage = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();

    final Directory _newDir = Directory('${_localStorage.path}/$folderName/');

    if (await _newDir.exists()) {
      return _newDir.path;
    }
    else {
      final Directory _newAppDir = await _localStorage.create(recursive: true)
      return _newAppDir.path;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to use `final Directory _newAppDir = await _newDir.create(recursive: true)` instead of `final Directory _newAppDir = await _localStorage.create(recursive: true)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create existing directory (root directory returned by getApplicationSupportDirectory method).

Instead of:

```
final Directory _newAppDir = await _localStorage.create(recursive: true);
```

You need to use:

```
final Directory _newAppDir = await _newDir.create(recursive: true)
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I have fixed it